# Typescript error TS1110 & TS1005

Tags: typescript

`TypeScript error: typings/node/node.d.ts(83,23): Error TS1110: Type expected.`
`TypeScript error: typings/node/node.d.ts(1830,52): Error TS1005: '=' expected.`

TypeScript compilation breaks on `node.d.ts`, I have tried reinstalling `node.d.ts` to no avail.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same error when I was using typescript version 1.7.3
with node 5.0.0

I upgraded to the latest typescript, 1.8.9, and the above errors disappeared.

The hint was in node.d.ts#17:

> // compat for TypeScript 1.8